# Responsive design not working in iphone 5s

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, simulator

I am using a responsive design , which is working perfectly in simulator (http://iphone5csimulator.com/). But on iphone5s , the design is broken.I am using css style like `@media (max-width: 320px) {}`. Is anyother way to make it perfect? Is there any other simulator is availabe for testing?

In simulator

[image]

In iphone

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
/* iPhone 5 Retina regardless of IOS version */
@media (device-height : 568px) 
   and (device-width : 320px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
/* and (orientation : todo: you can add orientation or delete this comment)*/ {
                 /*IPhone 5 only CSS here*/
}
```

or try with @media screen

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {

}
```

check out browser stack they have lots of mobile emulators..-[Link](http://www.browserstack.com/)